# Auto increment a field without sequence in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, auto-increment

I am trying to increment a field without sequence . Is there any possiblities??
 can i do something like this

```
INSERT INTO Test 
VALUES ((
         SELECT COUNT(ID) 
         FROM Test)+1)
```

Please suggest me a way to do this

Comment: "*I am trying to increment a field without sequence*". Why would you ever want to do that? Using `max()` (or even worse: `count()`) is either dead slow and not scalable or plain wrong in a multi-user environment.

Comment: In multiuser environment, there are NO scaleable possibilities. The reason is ACID - your session can not see uncommited data from other session. This also applies to max value computation. BTW: the newest version Oracle 12c has auto-increment implemented.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't you want to use a sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sequence field is called seq_fld for example you could use

```
insert into Test values ( (select max(seq_fld) from Test) + 1)
```

It is advisable to have unique constraint on seq_fld

Comment: But if it is the first record it will throw NULL . So i guess its better to use COUNT instead of MAX . What do you think?

Comment: if we put aside the fact that this is simply not the right way to implement incrementing of a column value in a multiuser environment, that query will still produce incorrect result if we replace `insert into ... values(...)` statement with `insert into .. select .. from..`

Comment: In order to cover first insert you can use "select NVL(max(seq_fld), 0) from Test"

Answer (score 1):

you can take the current maximum value in a variable with `@var_name = SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM TABLE`

then you can make use of `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_name)+@var_name`